# Javascript code is showed in single line in ie10 developer tool

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ie-developer-tools

Having problem with debugging javascript code in IE10. When page loads, my scripts are shown in single line, which makes step-by-step debugging impossible.
 Is there any way to get my code displayed the way I wrote it?

Comment: It's minified to make loading from cache faster. Google JavaScript beautifier.

Comment: I don't have IE10 here to play with -- could it be an issue with Unix EOLs?

Comment: Solved by clearing cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may have resolved this issue yourself. However, in the future if you ever want to "pretty print" minified single-lined javascript code, click the Configuration button (looks like a hammer+wrench), and then click "Format JavaScript"

You can learn more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg699336(v=vs.85).aspx#prettyprintscript